# Verify .class file against classpath

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I'm looking for a way to check a .class against a classpath to ensure that all of the class's dependencies are available in the classpath.

E.g.  How would I write a method like this:

`public boolean checkDependencies(File classFile, URL[] classpath)`
or
`public boolean checkDependencies(Class cls, URL[] classpath)`

such that they would return `true` only if all methods and fields used in the the class can be resolved in the given classpath.

Bonus if there is a way to provide accurate source line numbers like javac if a method reference cannot be found.

Comment: why do you want to do that ? You will anyway get exception if classnotfound

Comment: I'm using the Kotlin compiler to compile some Kotlin files but it doesn't seem to have a bootclasspath option like javac does.  So some of the .class files it produces might not work with the subset of the JRE that my runtime environment has.  I want to be able to detect these dependency problems at compile-time, like you can using the bootclasspath option in javac.